# PHP Fatal Error : Call to undefined function

Tags: php, session, sendmail, phpmailer

I have this script where I am trying to send an email to the users when the site's admin deletes their account(s).

I am currently doing this by user three files: adminprocess, session and mailer.

When an admin submits a username to be deleted the actions takes place in the adminprocess. php, then adminprocess.php calls the session's function (sendUserdeleted()). sendUserdeleted(0 has a reference to the mailer's class object and a function.

For better understanding I have attached the codes below doing the job.

**1 Adminprocess.php**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rel))
  {
        $email = $row['email'];
        $name = $row['name'];
  }

  $session->sendUserdeleted($name,$email);
  header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
```

**2 session.php**

```
function sendUserdeleted($name,$email)
{
 global $database, $form, $mailer;  //The database, form and mailer object<br/>
 $mailer->senddeleted($name,$email);
 return 0;  //New user added succesfully
}
```

**3 Mailer.php**

```
class Mailer 
{


   function senddeleted($name,$email)
   {
    $from = "From: ".EMAIL_FROM_NAME." <".EMAIL_FROM_ADDR.">"; 
        $subject = "Lab Scheduler - Account deleted!"; 
        $body = $name.",\n\n"."Your account from our system has been deleted"<br/>
         return mail($email,$subject,$body,$from);
   }
};

/* Initialize mailer object */
$mailer = new Mailer;

?>
```

I don't understand why I am unable to send a mail. Whenever I select a user to be deleted and submit the value, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mailer::senddeleted() in
>   D:\Hosting\9769324\html\lab\include\session.php on line 408

That's how the mail isn't getting sent. Though, I the user is getting deleted without any issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do u have `<br/>` in a `php` file?? :o

Comment: You should init the Mailer in session.php

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 : please avoid editing code form your end....edit history shows you added `<br/>`...!!

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Initialize mailer object */
$mailer = new Mailer;
```

This should be in your session.php

Comment: I added the code to my function sendUserdeleted($name,$email) in session.php as below:function sendUserdeleted($name,$email){
global $database, $form, $mailer;  //The database, form and mailer object
$mailer = new Mailer;
$mailer->senddeleted($name,$email);

return 0;  //New user added succesfully
}

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('Mailer.php');

function sendUserdeleted($name,$email){
    global $database, $form;  //The database, form and mailer object

    $mailer = new Mailer;
    $mailer->senddeleted($name,$email);

    return 0;  //New user added successfully
}
```

include `Mailer.php` in `session.php` and create an instance of `mailer`

Answer (score 0):

add `<?php include('Mailer.php') ?>` in **session.php**

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the `<br>` from mailer.php file.
2. Include `mail.php` in `session.php` like `include("Mailer.php")`
3. Instantiate an object of mail class in `session.php` `$mailer = new Mailer;`

you have already a `$mailer` object in `Mailer` class so this should work in `session.php`

```
   include('Mailer.php');

   function sendUserdeleted($name,$email){
        global $database, $form, $mailer ;  //The database, form and mailer object


        $mailer->senddeleted($name,$email);

        return 0;  //New user added succesfully
    }
```